# Manage search results in Langchain

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I am kind of new to Langchain. I wanted to create an app that uses Langchain's search agents like serpapi and find some useful information on the internet. But most of the times, when I want references from it, it returns irrelevant sources. I want to manage what it searches. How can I do that in python?

I have searched for the solutions and found custom tools but they were not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The search results depend on the keyword your LLM used to search. The LLM chooses keywords to search based on your provided information (prompt). So, you have three options here:

- Optimize your prompt so that your LLM can follow correctly. Maybe
  give it some examples (in case of a few-shot react description).
- After receiving a search result, try to ask your LLM to extract
  relevant information and refine the result. You can check [this
  explanation](https://medium.com/@gartist/make-langchain-agent-actually-works-with-local-llms-vicuna-wizardlm-etc-da42b6b1a97).
- In case you're using local LLM, try a bigger LLM. As far as we know,
  a bigger model has a better reasoning ability.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to manipulate the search result is using the prompt. Specify the goal clearly, add examples, Do not add contradictory ideas.